# how can I draw contour line in python?

Tags: python, contour, contourf

Im studying about python contour.

in now, I try to draw the line in contourf.

my code is like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker, cm
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x=np.array([800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800,
            1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000,
            1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200,
            1300, 1300, 1300, 1300, 1300, 1300,
            1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1400,
            1600, 1600, 1600, 1600, 1600, 1600,
            1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800,
            2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000,
            2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200,
            2300, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2300,
            2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400])
y=np.array([95.7,   235.9,  474.6,  661,    801.8, 958.5,
            108,    270.3,  539.5,  755.8, 916.8,   1102.5,
            144.9,  362,    723,    1013.4, 1230.4, 1469,
            146.1,  364, 728.1, 1018.8, 1236.5, 1466.7,
            144.9, 362.1,   724.1,  1013.9, 1231.1, 1449,
            143,    357.2,  713,    997.7,  1212.1, 1423.5,
            136.1,  341,    682,    955.1,  1159.9, 1365.7,
            127.1,  318.1,  635,    889.9,  1079.9,1272.1,
            115,    287.1,  574.9,  804.1,  976.9,1156.3,
            108,    270.1,  540,    754.9,  917.1,1072.6,
            86.1, 225.6,    260.5,  617.2,  749.2,  875])
z=np.array([1.5,    2.7,    4.8,    10.2,   19.1,   41.3,
            1.6,    2.3,    3.4,    6.4,    17.6,   46.5,
            1.9,    2.8,    6.9,    16.5,   35.8,   63.4,
            2.4,    3.4,    5.8,    11.8,   25.6,   47.3,
            2.9,    3.7,    5.8,    11.5,   23.1,   36.1,
            3.2,    4.2,    5.3,    10.6,   16.5,   26.8,
            3.5,    4.2,    5.4,    7.3,    13.8,   17.6,
            3.7,    4.3,    5.6,    6.2,    10.6,   12.8,
            4.3,    4.6,    5.4,    5.9,    8.3,    10.9,
            4.7,    5,  5.2,    5.6,    6.4,    9.3,
            4.8,    4.9,    5.3,    5.9,    5.2,    6.7
])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = griddata((x, y), z, (X, Y), method='nearest')


#plt.contour(X,Y,Z,levels=256, alpha=1.0, cmap='jet', extend='both')

contours = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels=1000, alpha=1.0, cmap='jet', extend='max', method='linear')
plt.title('OPACITY')
plt.xlabel('SPEED [RPM]')
plt.ylabel('TORQUE [Nm]')
plt.colorbar()

plt.show
```

if i run this code, i get a graph like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlUmj.png)

but I need to draw a graph with same contour line.

there is for example what I exactly want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1zxZ.png)

how can i fix my code??